# Prevent truncating of a shared mapped file?

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I have two processes that communicate through shared memory. One is privileged and trusted, the other is an LXC process and untrusted.

The trusted process creates a file in a directory that the LXC process can access. It sets it to a fixed size with ftrucnate.

Now it shares that file with the untrusted process by both of them mapping it read+write.

I want the untrusted process to be able to read and write to the mapping, which is safe, because the trusted process makes no assumptions about what has been written and carefully validates it.

However, with write access the untrusted process can ftruncate the file to zero (it can't increase it's size due to mount restrictions) and this causes a SIGBUS in the privileged process (I confirmed this.)

Since there are many untrusted processes which communicate with the trusted one, this is basically a denial of service attack on the entire system, and Linux permits it. Is there any way to prevent this?

I could deny access to ftruncate, but there may be other system calls to do the same thing. Surely there is a way to allow a process to write to a file but not to resize it or rename it or make any other meta data changes?

The best I can think of is fallback to the archaic System V shared memory, because that cannot be resized at all on Linux (not even by the priveledged process.)

Comment: No, that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using Unix Domain Sockets instead? They are often overlooked, but they provide a better security, easier locking, and almost as fast as shared memory.

Comment: Yes, they would be much easier to use. But they're far too slow. Even locking is too slow. I can't have a single syscall on the fast path.

Comment: Have you considered handling `SIGBUS` in the privileged process?

Comment: Yes, I considered handling SIGBUS, but using the System V interface is the lesser evil.

Comment: Elof, how do you synchronize the SM access without syscalls? With proper locking the performance is almost identical.

Comment: @fibonacci It's a spsc queue, so only one process can write to the region. Synchronization is not required if one is careful about the order of writes and reads (requires memory barriers outside of x86/x64.) Even locking does not need to use syscalls these days on the fast path with futexes (fast userspace mutexes support in Linux.)

Answer (score 2):

Since Linux version 3.17 you can use file seals for that purpose. They are supported only on tmpfs, so will work with POSIX shared memory and with shared files created with `memfd_create()`. Before handing the file descriptor to untrusted process call `fcntl(fd, F_ADD_SEALS, F_SEAL_SHRINK)` and your trusted process is safe from SIGBUS.

For details see manual pages for `memfd_create()` and `fcntl()`.